# PHP MongoDB Nested $or and $and

Tags: php, mysql, mongodb

I'm trying to get the mysql equivalent for the below query in MongoDb.

MySQL = `select * from db_name where ('checkin_date' >=$checkin && 'checkout_date' <= $checkin) or   ('checkin_date' >=$checkout  && 'checkout_date' <= $checkout)`

Below is the current code.. However i couldnt get it to work. The Data's and variables are correct. I Have tried with single $and and $or and they seem to work perfectly. But i get confused while nesting OR and AND

```
  $cond = array(
               '$or' => array(
                  '$and' => array(
                    array( 'checkin_date' =>  array('$gte'=>$checkin) ),
                    array( 'checkout_date' =>  array('$lte'=>$checkout) )
                  ), 
                  '$and' => array(
                      array( 'checkin_date' =>  array('$gte'=>$checkin) ),
                      array( 'checkout_date' =>  array('$lte'=>$checkout) )
                  )
                )
            );
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Can you please provide the values of $checkin and $checkout?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example there is an error:

```
select * from db_name 
where  (
    'checkin_date' >= $checkin 
    && 'checkout_date' <= $checkin
) or (
    'checkin_date' >= $checkout  
    && 'checkout_date' <= $checkout
)
```

So first and 2 times $checkin and next one has 2 times $checkout.
But your $cond var does use 1 $checkin and 1 $checkout. It should be the following based on your mysql example:

```
 $cond = array(
               '$or' => array(
                  '$and' => array(
                    array( 'checkin_date' =>  array('$gte'=>$checkin) ),
                    array( 'checkout_date' =>  array('$lte'=>$checkin) ) // $checkin
                  ), 
                  '$and' => array(
                      array( 'checkin_date' =>  array('$gte'=>$checkout) ), // $checkout
                      array( 'checkout_date' =>  array('$lte'=>$checkout) )
                  )
                )
            );
```

When I'm working on such nested SQLs, it helps me to indent them, then I can check them row for row.